# Unable to show different div if data is empty

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-directives

I'm a beginner to angular 2 and unable to understand how to show a different div if list is empty.I have written and ngIf to check if data exists.Searched online and all results ask me to check length or use ! symbol but it does not work.Below is my github of the project and below it is the json result which i want to show list empty condition as well.

[Git](https://github.com/sainath034/Angular-2-Example)

**Json output**

```
{"status_message":"Success","status_code":"0","Registers":null}
```

I was expecting to show a message called no data in List Component

Comment: can you post your code with *ngIf, will be easier to answer!

Comment: iproducts: IEmail[]; is wrong , I think , beacuse you are not storing array init but json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your json returns a null instead of an empty string, you should be able to just do an ngIf check on that data point

```
<!-- list.component.html -->
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor='let lst of iproducts.Registers'>
    ...
  </tr>
  <tr *ngIf='!iproducts.Registers'>
      <td colspan="3">No List Data Found</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```